# BizTalk cannot connect to application insights

Tags: azure, biztalk, biztalk-2016, azure-application-insights

I try to connect BizTalk 2016 to Azure Application insights.

I copy paste the Instrumentation Key from Azure to Group Settings, but when I click OK I get the next error

[image]

Comment: I take it you have done the pre-requisites?  1. Create a new instance of Application Insights.  2. Install Feature Pack 1 on your BizTalk Server.  As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/send-tracking-data-to-azure-application-insights-using-biztalk-server?redirectedfrom=MSDN#prerequisites

Comment: I do everything. After some investigation, I found out, that although I get an error when I apply the Analytics settings, connection is established and I can get data. In another BizTalk server, settings are applied without error.